# django - post data query dict is empty

Tags: python, json, django, rest, post

i use postman app and set `content-type : application/json`
and using `post` method 
in the body i select `"raw" and "JSON(application/json)"`
and after all of this i enter a simple json :

> {"token":"ghdfhldfigpd","text":"test Expense" ,"amount":10000}

but when i debug my django app : query dict is empty [see this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xTfnC.png)

but when i enter my data in form-data section 
my app works and post query dict is not empty
what the problem should be ?

EDIT : i see that the data goes to body but not to post query dict:
[this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NBhIf.png)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

[`request.POST`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.POST) is only for `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` data. Since you are using json, you should use `request.body` with `json.loads`.

```
import json

def my_view(request):
    data = json.loads(request.body.decode('utf-8'))
    ...
```

Comment: Why isn't this more well know? Maybe the docs need to be updated to reflect this in light of the prevalence of frontend frameworks

Comment: @Sevenearths adding a warning to the docs is a good idea. Why not create a ticket, or even better, draft a patch.